# Windows Forms Application - axvlcplugin2 error in Release mode

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc

I'm currently using axVLCPlugin2 in my Windows forms application.

I imported it from COM Components and axAXVLC and AXVLX are added to references. Everything works as expected in debug mode.

But it throws an exception in Release mode when I try to load the form that contains the plugin (Form3). It says:

> system.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error
>   occurred in GDI+.'

in Form3.Designer.cs at

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axVLCPlugin21)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Also an error message pops up saying :

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.

I'm sure that the problem is with plugin as everything works fine when the plugin is removed from form.

Below is my code for Form3.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public string source;

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.Size = this.Size;
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(source, null, null);
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
        }

        private void Form3_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.Size = this.Size;
        }

        private void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using vs community 2017, my target platform is .net 4.5 and vlc Version 2.2.6(Latest Stable).

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?
Sorry for longer description and thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be an x86/x64 problem. check your debug settings what processor target is set and what platform is preferred and if those differs from the release settings... f.e.: AnyCpu and 32bit preferred might work in debug mode but AnyCpu without 32bit preferred would fail in a release build...

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the problem partially. Now, I'm able to run the application on my computer but gives an error "A generic error occurred in GDI+" when executed on a different machine.

Comment: Well, more infos would be useful. What cpu target did you choose? when/where does the error occur? Are there more error details? What are the differences between both machines (x86 or x64 os, dotnet framework, ...)?

Comment: I created release using anycpu target and ran executable on x64 machine with dotnet 4.5. Error occurs when trying to start Form3 from a button in Form2

Comment: So both machines are x64, have the same OS, the same dotnetfx and can run x64-VLC normally from outside your application?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.

Comment: Sorry to say, but then i'm out of ideas :(